# Toggle class in a nested List

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure with me

```
<ul id="Budor">
   <li class="L-1">First
    <ul>
       <li class="L-2">First Child
          <ul>
              <li>abc</li>
              <li>xyz</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="L-2">Second Child
          <ul>
              <li>pqr</li>
              <li>dfg</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

I am adding +/- icons in front of the nodes. The css for this structure

```
.handle { 
    background: transparent url( /images/openedclosed.png ) no-repeat left top; 
}

.closed { background-position: left top; }
.opened { background-position: left -5px; }
```

On the click event, I want to use a toggleClass to toggle between + and - depending on the expand/ collapse state

```
  $('#Budor li').on('click', function (e) { 
         $(this).children('ul').slideToggle().toggleClass('handle closed', 'handle opened');
  });
```

However this is not working. What am I doing wrong?

**[Extra Info]:** Every parent and child list that has nodes within it can be opened and will have the expand (+). When the user clicks to expand the node, the (+) should change to (-). When the node is clicked again it collapses and (-) is changed to (+).

Comment: Please provide a demo (http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are the lists you want to mark as closed/open but is it something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jLL9uwLc/)?

```
$('#Budor li').on('click', function (e){
     $("#Budor>li>ul").toggleClass('closed');
     $("#Budor>li>ul").toggleClass('opened');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('#Budor li').on('click', function (e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children("ul").toggleClass('closed').toggleClass('opened');
  });
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5vhu7auf/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use e.target instead of this in your JS code. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/snitin_78/omd726ed/) is working fiddle. Below is the code with some other changes beyond e.target:

```
$('li').on('click', function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).children('ul').is(':visible')) {
            $(e.target).children('ul').slideToggle().toggleClass('closed');
        }
        else
            $(e.target).children('ul').slideToggle().toggleClass('opened');
        e.stopPropagation();
});
```